# Rails 4: complex search form to filter a model through various relationships

Tags: forms, search, ruby-on-rails-4, report, analytics

I'm working on some reporting/analytics for a site.  The goal is to filter to a group of @loans that I query from the DB and run analytics against.  The desire is to use the DB to grab the filtered @loans, run metrics against those records, and then return the metrics to display on the page.

The relationships are not very complex but what I'm doing feels like it is:

**Model relationships**

```
# loan.rb
belongs_to :loan_category
belongs_to :loan_type
belongs_to :partner

# loan_category.rb
has_many :loans

# loan_type.rb
has_many :loans

# partner.rb
has_many :loans
belongs_to :company

# company.rb
has_many :partners
```

**Filter form**

I'm treating reports as a resource since users can save filters as a saved_report.

A user filters by 2 given criteria:

1. what type of report they want (partner, company, loan_category, loan_type), accomplished by selecting ONLY one of the four (ie, filter by `parter ID#3`, or `loan_type ID#6`, but never more than one)
2. date range (from, to)

At first it seems fairly trivial, until I start trying to implement this.  The issue is that the various situations must be accounted for:

1. need an overview report that ONLY filters by date range (basically a dashboard page), so that if a user does NOT select any report type and only provides dates, you display the overview report
2. need to filter by provided type (partner, company, loan_category, loan_type) AND date range
3. need to allow users to save a filter as a saved_report to quickly filter by the criteria when they select that report

I'm trying to accomplish this in a pretty ugly fashion.  These examples will demonstrate what I mean:

- `/reports` => overview report, default to current month
- `/reports?from=2014-01-01` => overview report, from given date to current day
- `/reports/3` => a saved_report, which COULD filter by any of the four (partner, company, loan_category, loan_type) and a date range
- `/reports/partner?partner_id=3` => using `params[:id]` in a hackish fashion, my controller code knows I want to filter by a given partner
- `/reports/loan_type?loan_type_id=7&from=2014-01-01&to=2014-01-31` => again using `params[:id]` I know to filter by a given loan_type with a specified date range

This leads to some very ugly controller code:

**Reports controller**

```
# always overview report; just filter by specified date range
def index
  # Dummy code to show what I'm doing...
  @loans = Loan.where(created_at >= params[:from]).where(created_at <= params[:to])

  # ...use @loans to calculate metrics for report...
end

def show
  is_saved_report = false
  @saved_report = nil

  # feels very "hackish" to do this...
  case params[:id]
    when "partner"
      @loans = Loan.where(partner_id: params[:partner_id])
    when "company"
      @loans = Loan.includes(:partner).where(partner.company_id: params[:company_id])
    when "loan_category"
      @loans = Loan.where(loan_category_id: params[:loan_category_id])
    when "loan_type"
      @loans = Loan.where(loan_type_id: params[:loan_type_id])
    else
      # if none of the 4 "keywords" was used, assume it's a saved_report ID
      is_saved_report = true
      @saved_report = SavedReport.find(params[:id])

      # grab filters from @saved_report and use them to run ANOTHER case statement...
  end

  # add date range filters    
  if is_saved_report == true
    @loans.where(created_at >= @saved_report.from).where(created_at <= @saved_report.to)
  else
    @loans.where(created_at >= params[:from]).where(created_at <= params[:to])
  end

  # at this point, should have filtered list of @loans to run metrics on
  @total_loans = @loans.size

  # ...have to have more conditionals to display metrics for specific type of report...
end
```

As you can see, the code gets VERY UGLY very quickly.  There has to be a better way of approaching this.  I simply cannot think of a cleaner solution.  I've been working on this problem so long now that I'm not thinking clearly on it.

I'm open to any suggestions or thoughts on this situation.  Something that at first seemed trivial is becoming a bit of a nightmare.